# How to get a JSON object from Servlet using HTTPURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I'm writing an Android App which manages login using java Servlet.
Login Data is checked in an MySQL Database.
This servlet should return a json Object.
Below Some Code:

Servlet:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package AndroidControllers;

import Database.Authentication;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author serge
 */
public class Android extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Android</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Android at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            String user = request.getParameter("username");
            String pass = request.getParameter("password");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            JSONObject logged = Authentication.login_json(user, pass);
            if(logged != null)
                writer.print(logged);
            else{
                logged.put("type", "ERROR");
                logged.put("username", "ERROR");
                writer.print(logged);
            }
        //processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        processRequest(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Authentication.login_json Method:

```
public static JSONObject login_json(String user, String pass){
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Connection conn = null;
        String sql = "select username, user_type from users where username = '" + user +
                "' and password = '" + pass + "';";
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = Utilities.connect();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                json.put("username", user);
                json.put("type", rs.getString("user_type"));
            }
            else{
                json.put("username", "FAIL");
                json.put("type", "FAIL");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ecc){
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ecc.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            Utilities.disconnect(conn);
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Authentication Method used in Android:

```
    package com.example.serge.biblioteca;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
public class http_authentication{
    public static JSONObject login_json(String user, String pass) {
        String json_string = "";
        JSONObject stream = new JSONObject();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String url = "http://localhost:43746/Progetto_TWEB/Android?username=" + user
                + "&password=" + pass;
        try {
            URL link = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();

            // Check the connection status
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                // if response code = 200 ok
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                // Read the BufferedInputStream
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                json_string = sb.toString();
                stream = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json_string);

                // End reading...............
                // Disconnect the HttpURLConnection
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } else {
                // Do something
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        // Return the data from specified url
        return stream;
    }
}
```

These methods used in a normal Java class work good, they always return expected json object. In the Andoid App I always get an empty json object and I have no idea why.

Here's the Activity code:

```
package com.example.serge.biblioteca;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Created by serge on 28/12/2017.
 */

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_login);
        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        JSONObject logged = new JSONObject();
        boolean vuoto = false;
        String logged_type = "";
        String logged_user = "", user_type = "";
        TextView welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.normal_intro);
        String user = username.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();
        try {
            logged = http_authentication.login_json(user, pass);
                vuoto = logged.isEmpty();
//The following setText always returns an empty String so I think the object is null
                username.setText(logged.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ecc){
            username.setText(ecc.getMessage());
        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Could you guys help me understand why Android Activity always gets a null Object, but a normal java class works well?
Thank you

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error, I just get an empty String

Comment: "json_string" is empty after "login_json" method is called?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to modify the method in order to return the same thing but as a String. In Normal Java Class works well, in Android Activity always empty/null

Comment: There's a lot of noise in the question which you can just boil down yourself. More than half of the code can be omitted to clarify the question and magnify the actual problem for yourself. This problem is not related to JSON objects. This problem is not related to logins. This problem is irrelevant of whatever the servlet is doing, even if it simply returns a "Hello World" test string. You should be paying attention to whether getResponseCode() really returns 200 and also to exception logging. You should be asking yourself over and over what exactly "localhost" in the servlet URL means.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. 
If someone wonders how I'm going to explain below:

First of all, I created a new Servlet which does the same thing but with much less code:

```
package AndroidControllers;
import Database.Authentication;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        JSONObject logged = Authentication.login_json(username, password);
        if(!logged.isEmpty()){
            out.println(logged);
        }
        else{
            logged.put("username", "NULL");
            logged.put("type", "NULL");
            out.println(logged);
        }
    }
}
```

This servlet gets two parameters (username and password) and checks if they exist MySQL Database. If they exist it returns a JSONObject of type: {"username": "username", "type":"admin" or "type":"normal"}.
The Authentication.login_json(username, password) method is the same...

I also developed again the Android Activity:

```
package com.example.serge.biblioteca;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class login_page extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button login;
    EditText user, pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        findViewsByID();
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void findViewsByID(){
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_login);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        String URL = "http://192.168.1.4:43746/Progetto_TWEB/Login?username=" + username
                + "&password=" + password;
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            JSONObject output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                String json_string = getOutputFromUrl(url);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                try {
                    output = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json_string);
                }
                catch(ParseException ecc){

                }
            }
            return output;
        }

        private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject output) {
            Intent redirect_normal = new Intent(login_page.this, normal_user.class);
            String type = output.get("type").toString();
            if(type.equals("normal"))
                startActivity(redirect_normal);
            else if(type.equals("NULL"))
                user.setText("LOGIN FAILED");
            else if(type.equals("admin"))
                user.setText("NOT NORMAL");

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Activity can communicate with Servlet using AsyncTask, HTTPURLConnection and InputStream.
This time everything works fine since Android Activity gets expected JSONObject.
I'd like to say Thank You to all guys who helped me here.
Hope this is useful for someone and Sorry for my English.